# Setting UITextView.textColor has no effect?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextview

I have a plain (no attributed text) `UITextView` in a `UITableViewCell`. I set the `UITextView` `textColor` to 'ColorSwatch.Clay' (a color close to white) in the main storyboard (background is a dark color).
 **No effect: text still black.**

Even when setting the `textColor` explicitly in the cell just before setting the **text has no effect.**

Please help, this is driving me nuts ! This is probably something incredibly stupid but I'd rather feel stupid and keep my sanity.

Updated: Here is some code:

UITableViewDataSource:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let reviewCell = self.reviewTable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ReviewTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReviewTableViewCell
    reviewCell.configureFor(reviewManager[indexPath.row])
    return reviewCell
}
```

ReviewTableViewCell:

```
@IBOutlet weak var rating: StarRating!
@IBOutlet weak var authorAndDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var reviewTextArea: UITextView!

func configureFor(review: Review) {
    rating.rating = review.rating

    let authorName = review.author["fullname"] as? String ?? review.author.username
    let date = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(review.updatedAt!, dateStyle: .ShortStyle, timeStyle: .NoStyle)

    // For some reason the textColor specified in the storyboard is overriden somewhere...
    reviewTextArea.textColor = ColorSwatch.Clay

    reviewTextArea.text = review.text
}
```

Comment: can you show some code? maybe `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Answer (score 0):

It is like that.

`reviewTextArea.textColor` is overriding your `textColor`.

`ColorSwatch.Clay` is other color than White.

So, set White color programmatically to `reviewTextArea.textColor`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry no clay is my 'white' color. I edit my question.

Comment: Please check with commenting `reviewTextArea.textColor` line. Is color still black?

Comment: Yep. I thought somewhere my storyboard config was overridden so I decided to set the color as close as possible as where I thought it would be used and added this line but no luck and this is driving me nuts:)

Comment: Nope. Sorry that's all I can share. But I'll try to reproduce it an a smaller example...

Answer (score 0):

Case closed. I couldn't say what was wrong, but I had to refactor the UI: removed text view, add one back again... And no everything is fine. Sorry for the trouble.